# Bending a quarter circle into a line, growth of $r$

Tags: circles

Let's say we have a square with side length $a$. Let the center of the first circle be at a corner of the square and let $r = a$. If we want the circle to be the same as the diagonal of the square we need $r = \infty$.

Now I want to create more circles with $r = [a, \infty)$. Let's call the circle with $r = \infty$ fully bent and the circle with $r = a$ not bent at all. I want the circle to bend uniformly. For example: How do I calculate $r$ of a new circle if I want it to be in the middle between fully  bent and not bent at all?

Comment: I assume that the centers for circles with $r \not = a$ are *not* on the corner of the square? And that you want every circle to intersect with two corners of the square?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Consider the diagonal that goes through the center of the first circle. We know that every circle's center must be on this line, and every circle must intersect the *other* diagonal of the square at some point. For instance, on the infinite circle, it intersects it on its midpoint. Is your notion of "halfway-bent" that this intersection is halfway between where the first and infinite circles intersect the second diagonal?

Comment: Yes that is also true. I know how to calculate the length of each circle between the $2$ corners of the square that the circle goes through but I don't know if that helps. $l_p = r \alpha$ and $l_c = 2r \sin (\alpha / 2)$. $l_p$ is the length of the part of the circle and $l_c$ is the chord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AB$ be the diagonal of the square that is regarded as a arc of an infinite circle, and let $C$ be the corner of the square that is the centre of the first circle:

[image: Bending a quarter circle into a line]

In the general case, if the height of the circular segment $ADBF$ cut off by the chord $AB$ is $h,$ then
$$
r - \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{a^2}2} = h,
$$
therefore
$$
r + \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{a^2}2} = \frac{a^2}{2h},
$$
therefore
$$
r = \frac12\left(h + \frac{a^2}{2h}\right) = \frac{2h^2 + a^2}{4h}.
$$
Check: if
$$
h = a - \frac{a}{\sqrt2},
$$
then $2h^2 = (3 - 2\sqrt2)a^2,$ therefore
$$
r = \frac{(4 - 2\sqrt2)\sqrt2a^2}{4(\sqrt2 - 1)a} = a. \ \checkmark
$$
In the case of interest,
$$
h = \frac12\left(a - \frac{a}{\sqrt2}\right) = \frac{(\sqrt2 - 1)a}{2\sqrt2},
$$
therefore
$$
2h^2 = \frac{(3 - 2\sqrt2)a^2}4,
$$
therefore
$$
r = \frac{(7 - 2\sqrt2)2\sqrt2a^2}{4\cdot4(\sqrt2 - 1)a} = \frac{7 - 2\sqrt2}{4(2 - \sqrt2)}a = \frac{10 + 3\sqrt2}8a \bumpeq 1.7803a.
$$

---

More neatly:
$$
\frac{r}{a} = \frac12\left(\frac{h}{a} + \frac{a}{2h}\right).
$$

Check: if
$$
\frac{h}{a} = 1 - \frac1{\sqrt2},
$$
then
$$
\frac{a}{h} = 2\left(1 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\right),
$$
therefore
$$
\frac{r}{a} = \frac12\left(1 - \frac1{\sqrt2}\right) +
\frac12\left(1 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\right) = 1.\ \checkmark
$$

In the case of interest,
$$
\frac{h}{a} = \frac12\left(1 - \frac1{\sqrt2}\right),
$$
therefore
$$
\frac{a}{h} = 4\left(1 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\right),
$$
therefore
$$
\frac{r}{a} = \frac14\left(1 - \frac1{\sqrt2}\right) +
\left(1 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\right) =
\frac14\left(5 + \frac3{\sqrt2}\right) = \frac{10 + 3\sqrt2}8.
$$